# Community passing edits early with mod powers

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits, community-user

I noticed today, after suggesting an edit on SO, that one user reviewed it, yet it got passed.  After looking a little closer I noticed that user had *edited* my edit, causing Community to approve it.

[image]

Now normally it takes three users to approve an edit, but in this case I guess Community's mod powers passed it early.

Is this a bug or is there a reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. If any reviewer (while reviewing) edits the post, no other review is required for that post since editing by users with more than 2K reputation does not need any review. Thus editing while reviewing is approved/rejected by [Community ♦ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

If the suggested edit was too minor, the reviewer can reject it by removing the check mark of *Suggested edit was helpful*.